# What can be safely assumed about neighborhood operations near the edge/border?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

What can be safely assumed, when authors of a research article do not say/mention/hint anything about how they dealt with neighborhood operations close to image border?

My question may seem naive as some options are mentioned on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborhood_operation.

I am replicating a work reported in a journal article, where a 300x300 neighborhood around the current_point is used for computations. The authors did not mention how they dealt with border cases.

Comment: Email the author(s) and ask. It's surprising how many times this works.

Comment: There are some descriptions of the various ways ImageMagick treats *"missed pixels"* here... http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#virtual-pixel

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple ways to deal with borders:

1) Crop: Just get rid of the pixels. Typically implemented in software as filling in these outside values as 0s. Example:

```
                00000
123             01230
456    ---->    04560
789             07890
                00000
```

2) Extend: Simply "copy" the nearest edge pixels to the out of bounds areas. Example,

```
                11233
123             11233
456    ---->    44566
789             77899
                77899
```

or, keep going for however far your neighborhood/kernel needs to be.

3) Wrap: Just like Pacman. Example:

```
                97897
123             31231
456    ---->    64564
789             97897
                31231
```

In this case I arbitrarily chose to wrap diagonally (copied opposite corners). Some people like to interpolate the corners. I think this type of edge handling can be particularly useful if you plan on doing a Fourier Transform on your data (or maybe if it's already in frequency space, same idea as any type of spectral periodic wrapping), but I'm not really sure, I've never used it in practice.

4) Reflection: This is a method I've also never used, but have heard of it.
For example:

```
123             2112332
456    ---->    5445665
789             8778998
```

I chose not to pad in the top/bottom there, as it would be verbose.

It gets kind of tricking doing off-diagonals with some of these methods as well. You can either extend columns as needed to try to find the diagonals you might need, or interpolate to get the value.

Comment: Appreciate your elaborate answer. Out of the options you mention, which one is the adopted norm among researchers?

Comment: @GShah It depends on the specific problem. For the work that I do (radar processing), I've found that crop usually gets the job done. It's also simple enough to implement. Crop is always the first thing to try, and do something more fancy if that doesn't cut it. I really should have clicked your link before I answered, they literally list all these methods, just called different things haha. Sorry!I swear I didn't look at it before I answered haha. Can you link me the whitepaper, or even better, summarize it? FYI: I'm going to bed, and won't answer till tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In case of edge points, it is totally dependent on the operation you are performing. You need to see what kind of operation you are doing with an image (Specially at the edges/boundary).

The simplest way is to use zero padding.

```
       00000
123 => 01230
       00000
```

I don't know how you are implementing it (MATLAB/ OpenCV)?
Following link may be helpful for MATLAB implementation.
[MATLAB Neighborhood Operations](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/functionlist.html#bt5phd4-2)